# Convert kinect depth intensity to distance in meter

Tags: computer-vision, kinect

I'm working on kinect v1 depth images.
How do I find the distance in meters for the corresponding depth intensity value of each pixel?
The intensity value ranges from **0-255** since it is a grayscale image and i don't have the raw depth data.

I've tried various ways to get the distance, such as using the following formulas:

```
- 1.0 / (raw_depth * -0.0030711016 + 3.3309495161)  
- 0.1236 * tan(rawDisparity / 2842.5 + 1.1863)
```

I've also tried to get the raw data by using:

`raw = (255 - depthIntensity)/256*2047`

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Kinect actually sends something akin to a disparity image over USB. Both OpenNI and libfreenect are capable of converting that to a depth image using parameters reported by the device (baseline, focal length, and distance to reference plane, IIRC). e.g CV_CAP_PROP_OPENNI_BASELINE

In math form below, it is how we find the depth based on disparity

Depth = Baseline * focal length / disparity.  The depth should be corresponding to the Z axis of current image frame.

[image]

Comment: My problem is not about calculating depth, but how do i interpret the depth intensity value (0-255) from the depth image to distance in meters.

Comment: 0-255 is the value stored in the disparity image aka uchar or uint8. You need to convert to real in meter or in millimeter depth by  Z=B*f/disparity depth image is a float or double image which is not easily transmitted over the USB.  Unless Im post in Chinese and you dont understand, otherwise it is how you convert 0-255 to 0-N meters range

Comment: Oh sorry i misunderstood you earlier. Thanks for your suggestion, i'll try your method.